# How can I select a good monopod for under $100?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, monopod

We have two good questions that are similar to this [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3015/how-good-is-a-monopod) discusses how good monopods are. And [this one](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3745/tripod-for-upto-100) talks about tripods under $100. The second was the inspiration for this question.

I am looking for some possibilities for monopods with good stability for Canon XXXD class cameras with mid size telephotos like [70-200's](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3489/special-care-for-telephotos) under $100.

An added feature which would be ideal, is the ability to use the monopod as a hiking staff or walking stick.

A friend of mine also mentioned to me that he knew of a tripod which disassembled into two walking sticks and a third part. If you have any information on this, I would be very interested.

Comment: I got my Bogen 3018 for free on craigslist! Can't hike with it really, but still, that's a pretty good deal...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like the TrekPod.  I picked one of these up a year or so ago, and I love it.  As others have been quick to point out, it's no substitute for a real tripod, but it's a great hiking companion, IMO.

Comment: Could you comment on the stability and maybe a bit about your experience with it? This looks like a nice option, but I would like to hear more. Also what model do you have?

Comment: I've got the TrekPod II, which is the entry-level version.  Higher-end models break down smaller for traveling, and are lighter, I believe.

Comment: I take mine hiking, and I also took it on a 10-day canoe trip in Canada this spring.  It turned out to be a real help when portaging, as I ended up carrying an 80+ lb pack over portages up to a mile, and it was really nice to have a walking stick along.  I also ended up using it to pull myself out of a bog when my feet went into mud past my knees.

Comment: In terms of stability, it's not fantastic, as the legs are maybe 14" or so, but as long as you find reasonably level ground, it's not bad.  Worst case, you can hold it in place while you shoot.  In any event, it's a whole lot better than no tripod at all, which was the alternative if I hadn't brought it along.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I asked for, so I accepted it.

Answer (score 3):

The Canon Monopod 100 is a great budget monopod at ~$30.  Extends to 64.5", folds down to 21.3" (and attaches to my little bag quite easily), sturdy, nice ball head that holds a good bit of weight, makes a good walking stick on hikes and has a wrist strap.

I've used it with my Tamron 70-200mm f2.8 at airshows and for sports.  Works great on the tripod collar.

Answer (score 0):

A Manfrotto - 290 Series 59.4" Monopod is a good choice. It is easy to use but you should have a stable hand. It costs $54.

Comment: That has a maximum rating of 5kg, which I guess is enough, but do you think it's really sturdy enough for a large DSLR and 70-200mm?

Comment: @mike, you realize that Canon alone has 4 different 70-200 lenses, so its pretty hard to know how heavy and hard to carry one is without more details.

Comment: I would hope we're not going to have separate questions for each lens/body combination!  My point is whether a 5kg rating is really sufficient for a medium sized DSLR + zoom. Despite that combo weighing perhaps 3kg, I suspect it may not be suitably sturdy.